# ReactDOM Render of elements created with const

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I've been following a few tutorials and the [documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)I'm trying to make the following work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Composable Squares</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const Title = (props) => {
        const { text } = props;
        return React.createElement('h1', null, text);
    }
const App = (props) => {
    return React.createElement('div', null,
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title one!' } ),
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title two!!' } ),
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title three!!!' } )
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I'm getting the following message:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
>   you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
>   you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I've tried changing it to: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))` and I get `Unexpected token <`

How can I render the elements created by App?

Comment: I would very highly recommend using JSX instead of the `React.createElement` syntax. JSX is more concise, easier to read, and just generally less of a pain to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `App` is a function. [`ReactDOM.render()` expects an element as argument, not a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render).

The quickest solution is to just invoke `App()`:

```
ReactDOM.render(App(), document.getElementById('container'));
```

Or you can make `App` not a function, but assign to it the result of `React.createElement('div'...`.

**Demo:**

```js
const Title = (props) => {
        const { text } = props;
        return React.createElement('h1', null, text);
    }
const App = (props) => {
    return React.createElement('div', null,
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title one!' } ),
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title two!!' } ),
        React.createElement(Title, { text: 'Title three!!!' } )
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(App(), document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Composable Squares</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<!-- script src="script.js"></script -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use this,

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

You are getting error, because you are using `JSX` so you need a `babel`.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure when you add `babel`, you must add `type="text/babel"` on your script tag,

```
<script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/xexeriqabi/edit?html,output)

Read how to [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what the different syntax was on some of the tutorials I'm looking at. I was wondering about JSX.

Comment: @Silversail, using JSX is very simple and save's lot of time and space. Consider trying it.

Comment: I tried adding babel to my script tag but I'm getting: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. " Can I use babel for external js files or do I have to write everything in the index.html?

Comment: CORS policy error is from backend and not from frontend. You can use JSX in external js file, for that you need to provide `type="text/babel"` on script tag as show in answer.